# Hiding javaFX ColorPicker causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, javafx, lambda, javafx-8

In my fractal image generating program I allow the user to edit the colours of the onscreen image by displaying a javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker, as shown in the code below.

At the top I set up an event handler allowing the user to hide the ColorPicker and the GridPane wrapping it.   This works, in the sense that the intended behaviour occurs, but at the same time the JVM throws a NullPointerException.  The stack trace refers mainly to javafx classes and not at all to my executing class.

I have played around with the code and searched stackoverflow and beyond, but this one is stumping me.

Can anyone help me diagnose the cause please?   (Code and stack trace follow.)

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(ev2 -> {
    if (ev2.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
        System.out.println("\nEnter pressed, panel should hide...");
        huePanel.setVisible(false);     // press Enter to kill panel
        huePanel.getChildren().clear();
        root.getChildren().removeAll(huePanel);
    }
});     

huePanel = new GridPane();
huePanel.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
root.getChildren().addAll(huePanel);
int cl = colours[colourscheme].length;
Rectangle[] squares = new Rectangle[cl];
ColorPicker[] pickers = new ColorPicker[cl];

for (int i = 0; i < cl; i++) {
    int squareSize = width / 20;
    squares[i] = new Rectangle(squareSize, squareSize, colours[colourscheme][i]);
    squares[i].setStroke(BLACK);
    squares[i].setStrokeWidth(2.0);
    GridPane.setRowIndex(squares[i], (i / 8) * 2);
    GridPane.setColumnIndex(squares[i], i % 8);

    pickers[i] = new ColorPicker(colours[colourscheme][i]);
    GridPane.setRowIndex(pickers[i], (i / 8) * 2 + 1);
    GridPane.setColumnIndex(pickers[i], i % 8);

    huePanel.getChildren().addAll(squares[i], pickers[i]);
}
for (int j = 0; j < cl; j++) {
    indexOfColourToModify = j;
    pickers[j].setOnAction(ev1 -> {
            ColorPicker cp = (ColorPicker)(ev1.getSource());
            int k = huePanel.getChildren().indexOf(cp) / 2;     // really (idx-1)/2, as idx is odd
                                                                // due to squares[]
            Color c = cp.getValue();
            colours[colourscheme][k] = c;
            huePanel.requestLayout();
            System.out.println("\ncolours[" + colourscheme + "][" + k + "] set to " + c);
            paintImage(screenImage[screenImageIndex], realMinIts, realMaxIts);
        }
    );
}
```

=========================================================================

```
Enter pressed, panel should hide...
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl.positionAndShowPopup(ComboBoxPopupControl.java:197)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl.show(ComboBoxPopupControl.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ColorPickerSkin.show(ColorPickerSkin.java:464)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxBaseSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(ComboBoxBaseSkin.java:127)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ColorPickerSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(ColorPickerSkin.java:470)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
    at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.setShowing(ComboBoxBase.java:185)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.show(ComboBoxBase.java:391)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ComboBoxBaseBehavior.show(ComboBoxBaseBehavior.java:286)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ColorPickerBehavior.callAction(ColorPickerBehavior.java:82)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(BehaviorBase.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ComboBoxBaseBehavior.callActionForEvent(ComboBoxBaseBehavior.java:136)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.lambda$new$74(BehaviorBase.java:135)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3964)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3910)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2501)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:149)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:248)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I have a very similar exception, but when trying to use a `CheckComboBox` in a TableCell. [More details.](https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/7dj01s/checkcombobox_tablecell/)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can guess - I don't see much from the stack and your code other than it's attempting to:

```
_popup.show(comboBoxBase.getScene().getWindow(),
                snapPosition(p.getX()),
                snapPosition(p.getY()));
```

This likely may be due to the propagating event.

If your ColorPicker has focus, Enter will act on it, but at this point, it's been removed from the scene.

Try:

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(ev2 -> {
    if (ev2.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
        System.out.println("\nEnter pressed, panel should hide...");
        huePanel.setVisible(false);     // press Enter to kill panel
        huePanel.getChildren().clear();
        root.getChildren().removeAll(huePanel);
        ev2.consume();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that this exception is no longer thrown under Java 9 (build 9.0.1+11).   The code works as intended.

So I guess it was a Java/JavaFX bug of some kind.